# Seperate similar elements from two Lists and put remaining in another List

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a big list of Strings. I have a small list of strings which is actually a subset of big list of strings. Now I need to separate the matching items into a source list and non matching items into a target list.

I am able to separate matching items, but unable to create correct list of non matching items.

Below is the java code i wrote:

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> smallList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> bigList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> sourceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> targetList = new ArrayList<String>();

    smallList.add("jammu");
    smallList.add("surat");
    smallList.add("hyderabad");

    bigList.add("hyderabad");
    bigList.add("mumbai");
    bigList.add("delhi");
    bigList.add("jammu");
    bigList.add("patna");
    bigList.add("kanpur");
    bigList.add("surat");
    bigList.add("bangalore");
    bigList.add("chennai");
    bigList.add("kota");

    for(int i=0; i<smallList.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<bigList.size(); j++)
        {
            if(smallList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(bigList.get(j)))
            {
                targetList.add(smallList.get(i));
                break;
            }
                            else{
                                    targetList.add(bigList.get(j));
                            }

        }

    }

    System.out.println("========== Source List =============");
    System.out.println(sourceList);

    System.out.println("========== Target List =============");
    System.out.println(targetList);

}

}
```

Result is:

```
========== Source List =============
[hyderabad, mumbai, delhi, hyderabad, mumbai, delhi, jammu, patna, kanpur]
========== Target List =============
[jammu, surat, hyderabad]
```

What is want is:

```
========== Source List =============
[mumbai, delhi, patna, kanpur, bangalore, chennai, kota]
========== Target List =============
[jammu, surat, hyderabad]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Update: I cannot use removeAll to create a source list. Browsing through each record is mandatory to separate content.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the entire `bigList` into `sourceList` first. Then on a match, add it to `targetList` and remove from `sourceList`

```
for(int i=0; i<smallList.size();i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<bigList.size(); j++)
    {
        if(smallList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(bigList.get(j)))
        {
            targetList.add(smallList.get(i));
            sourceList.remove(smallList.get(i));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```